# How does this piece of cpp code dump?

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error

I meant to get some knowledge of `stack unwinding` and came across [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?),which demonstrates it with the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct E {
  const char* message;
  E(const char* arg) : message(arg) { }
};

void my_terminate() {
  cout << "Call to my_terminate" << endl;
};

struct A {
  A() { cout << "In constructor of A" << endl; }
  ~A() {
    cout << "In destructor of A" << endl;
    throw E("Exception thrown in ~A()");
  }
};

struct B {
  B() { cout << "In constructor of B" << endl; }
  ~B() { cout << "In destructor of B" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  set_terminate(my_terminate);

  try {
    cout << "In try block" << endl;
    A a;
    B b;
    throw("Exception thrown in try block of main()");
  }
  catch (const char* e) {
    cout << "Exception: " << e << endl;
  }
  catch (...) {
    cout << "Some exception caught in main()" << endl;
  }

  cout << "Resume execution of main()" << endl;
}
```

However it got core dumped when I compiled with *g++*/*clang++*.The output is as follows:

```
In try block
In constructor of A
In constructor of B
In destructor of B
In destructor of A
Call to my_terminate
已放弃 (核心已转储)   #core dump
```

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Well, your `terminate`... didn't terminate the program!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you are throwing an exception while you are throwing an exception.

In `main()`, you construct an A instance.  You then throw an exception.  *Before* it is caught, `A::~A` is called, which *also* throws an exception.  Having two exceptions in flight at the same time causes `terminate()` (or the user supplied equivalent) to be called (which, by default, calls abort(), which drops a core.  Either way, the program cannot recover.)

Aside: this is what leads to the general best practice rule where you must not throw exceptions in destructors unless you mean for it to kill your program.

Comment: *causes terminate to be called (which, by default, calls abort(), which drops a core*, You haven't seen the code properly.OP has an terminate handler in place.

Comment: @Als Yeah, I did.  I've updated my comment to reflect that, but it's entirely incidental to the point.

Comment: @KazDragon You mean the program cannot recover even if with `my_terminate()` specified?

Comment: @HongxuChen Not as far as I know.  From where would it make sense for the program to continue?

Answer (score 0):

`set_terminate()` expects the function providide to it *[terminate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/)* the program.

> Function that takes no parameters and returns void. The function **shall
>   not return** and shall **terminate** the program. terminate_handler is a
>   function pointer type taking no parameters and returning void.

set_terminate automatically calls abort() after calling your terminate function if you don't exit in the function provided.
Simply add `exit(0);` in `my_terminate()` to avoid seeing this abort() message.

Comment: The C++ standard(18.6.3.3) **does not** mandate `terminate()` to terminate the program.

Comment: @Als Did you read why I quote ? From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/)

Comment: For the record, the terminate handler gets called because A's destructor throws an exception as the stack is unwinding due to an exception (i.e. a double fault occurs).

Comment: That's not authoritative quote. This is though: "Required behavior: A terminate_handler shall terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller." from [terminate.handler].

Comment: C++ standard is the sole authority on matters governing the language it doesn't matter where you quote from.As a matter of fact the website where you quote from is notorious for incorrect information.